# How to create a Multi-Column Index or Unique Constraint with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

How to create a Multi-Column Index and/or Unique Constraint using NHibernate Mapping or Fluent NHibernate.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

assign a index/unique constraint name to more then one property

```
<property name="A" index="AB" />
<property name="B" index="AB" />
```

---

Theoretical it would also work with having more then one index on the same entity:

```
<property name="A" index="AB, ABC" />
<property name="B" index="AB, ABC" />
<property name="C" index="ABC" />
```

[But there is a bug.](http://216.121.112.228/browse/NH-1487) I also wrote a patch. if you are interested in this, please vote for the bug or add comment or something.

**Edit**: just checked what happened to [the bug](http://216.121.112.228/browse/NH-1487). It is fixed in version 2.1.0, so it should perfectly work now. Many thanks to the great NHibernate developer team!

Comment: For Fluent NHibernate you have to use SetAttribute, which'd make it something like:

Map(x => x.A).SetAttribute("index", "AB");

Comment: For anyone wondering, Fluent NHibernate now supports `.Index("IndexName...")`, rather than having to use `SetAttribute`.

Comment: It is important to say that the 'index' (and 'unique-key' too) property is used by NHibernate only when it generates a CREATE TABLE  statement and doesn't prevent NHibernate from trying to insert a duplicate row when using session.Save etc.

Answer (score 14):

Old, but I have something to add since I came across this same issue:

[Stefan Steinegger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27343/stefan-steinegger) answered correctly for *non*-unique multi-column indexes, but left out the code for *unique* multi-column indexes. For those you can use:

```
<property name="A" unique-key="AB" />
<property name="B" unique-key="AB" />
```

So, essentially the same but with a different attribute name.

---

An interesting thing to note is that for unique indexes, NHibernate generates its own name for the key, but for non-unique indexes it uses whatever you give it.

For example, the above code will NOT generate a unique index named "AB", but rather something like `UQ__TableName__7944C87104A02EF4`.

This is documented in [section 19.1.1](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#toolsetguide-s1-2) of the NHibernate documentation:

> Some tags accept an `index` attribute for specifying the name of an
>   index for that column. A `unique-key` attribute can be used to group
>   columns in a single unit key constraint. Currently, the specified
>   value of the unique-key attribute is *not* used to name the constraint,
>   only to group the columns in the mapping file.

However the following:

```
<property name="A" index="AB" />
<property name="B" index="AB" />
```

will just generate an index named "AB".