# Add a unique constraint on multiple columns with FluentNHibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, unique, constraints

I have a class that has a Primary Key as well as 2 foreign keys.  Foreign combinations  must be unique.  I do not see a way to do this (at least since SetAttribute was deprecated).

James touched on this with SetAttribute:
[How to create a Multi-Column Index or Unique Constraint with NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834565/how-to-create-a-multi-column-index-or-unique-constraint-with-nhibernate)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This might be useful to someone else, FNH mapping of unique constraint is accomplished like this:

`mapping.References<FirstClass>(x => x.FirstClass).UniqueKey("unique123");
 mapping.References<SecondClass>(x => x.SecondClass).UniqueKey("unique123");`

Further, it is explained that this only builds the constraint in the db, but that the developer is responsible to intercept duplicate insert attempts, otherwise an `SqlException` will be thrown saying an UNIQUE KEY constraint was violated.

[from the FNH group](http://groups.google.com/group/fluent-nhibernate/browse_thread/thread/fb801a8c6d59c9eb)