# NHibernate Composite Index, not a key

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, composite-index

Still a n00b in NHibernate :(

I want to add a composite index to the hbm.xml of one of my POCOs, for performance purposes.  It does not relate directly to a class, but rather two common values I will be querying against.

I think I need to do a `<map></map>` entry in the XML, but the XSD is asking for a class name on the `composite-key` element, and there is no direct relationship, per se... plus it's asking for more information than I think I would need to provide.  How do I do this?

```
    <map name="PropertyKeys">
        <key>
            <column name="StockID" />
            <column name="PropertyName" />
        </key>
            <composite-index class="Something?">
                <key-property name="What goes here?" />
            </composite-index>
        <what else goes here?>
    </map>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read this http://ayende.com/blog/4045/nhibernate-mapping-map It explains when you would use a map and further on it explains the `composite-index`

However without more background info it is not 100% certain that you need a map!

Comment: From what I understand, this is creating a key for an entity.  Am I misunderstanding?  I just want an index created on two columns, and I want to use that index when invoking my repository to look for certain small groups of values, not a unique value.

Comment: I am the one who is misundertanding your question. Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834565/how-to-create-a-multi-column-index-or-unique-constraint-with-nhibernate

Comment: that was it exactly.  It'd be great if they used the proper names for things.  Google is not a mind reader.  :)